# Insert Function using variable

Tags: excel, vba

Please correct my code

```
Dim Frm As Long

For Frm = 2 To Range("K100000").End(xlUp).Row - 1
    Range("L" & Frm).Formula = "=Product(J"&Frm,K"&Frm)"
Next Frm
```

Comment: "=Product(J" & Frm & ",K" & Frm & ")"

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a loop at all:

```
Sub test()
    Dim R As Range
    Set R = Range("L2:L" & (Range("K100000").End(xlUp).Row - 1))
    R.FormulaR1C1 = "=PRODUCT(RC[-2],RC[-1])"
End Sub
```

is functionally equivalent to your code (after your code has been fixed according to Tim Williams' comment).

`.FormulaR1C1` is often easier to use in VBA than `.Formula`. Note that to use it, you don't need to be actually using R1C1-style references in the spreadsheet itself (although temporarily enabling that option while developing the formula is helpful).